# C++ : How can I read all jpg files in a directory?

Tags: c++, jpeg, readfile

How can I read all jpg files in a directory?
These files are the frames of a film and their names are "0000.jpg" , "0001.jpg" ,... .

Comment: on what architecture? what libraries are you using? Boost/Stl/Qt? What have you tried?

Comment: hi I use Visual Studio , OpenCV , Qt and Win 7

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for something like `dir *.jpg` or `ls *.jpg` ?
In case you want to use boost in a form:

```
BOOST_FOREACH( const std::string& fname, ls( "./*.cpp" ))
    std::cout << fname << std::endl ;
```

You can use the ls function you can find here: http://greg-n-blog.blogspot.com/2010/01/ls-using-boost.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I am a newbie in c++ and opencv and I do not know anything about boost libraries.How can I learn about it?

Comment: Start here: http://www.boost.org/. However learning C++ has higher priority. Go to some bookstores, find a few books, buy a coffee or tea, sit down, and browse through them to see which you understand the best, and then buy it, and learn from it. School of course is the best, but I am assuming you have no such option.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions.I will go to that site and learn about boost libraries but I don't have time to do all of your offers:D Can I reach my purpose in few days?I am in a hurry!!!Oh look at the clock It's 1:00 am:(

Answer (score 1):

libjpeg is a popular jpeg decoder library

enumerating a directory can be done with a class in the boost library called:

```
boost::filesystem::directory_iterator
```